# Undefinded variable. Where's mistake?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm learning JS by making a simple game Whack-a-mole. I have problem with **randomPosition** in this script:

```
//delete mole from every grid
function randomSquare() {
  square.forEach((className) => {
    className.classList.remove("mole");
  })
  let randomPosition = square[Math.floor((Math.random) * 9)];
  randomPosition.classList.add("mole");

  hitPosition = randomPosition.id;
}

square.forEach((id) => {
  id.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    if (id.id === hitPosition) {
      result += 1;
      score.textContent = result;
    }
  });
});

//move mole on the grid
function moveMole() {
  let timerId = null;
  timerId = setInterval(randomSquare, 1000);
}

moveMole();


function countDown() {
  currentTime--;
  timeLeft.textContent = currentTime;

  if (currentTime === 0) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    alert("Game over! Your final score is" + result);
  }
}

let timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```

Error from console: TypeError: randomPosition is undefined app.js:15:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.random function call is missing

```
  let randomPosition = square[Math.floor((Math.random()) * 9)];
```